# tvOS: How can I get the gyroscopes data? (Objective-C)

Tags: rotation, accelerometer, gyroscope, tvos, siri-remote

I´m working on a app that uses the pitch rotation, I need to track a movement in an arch of +30º -30º...

The problem is that despite Siri-Remote has a gyroscope, when I use the GameController framework the rotation rate is always returning 0 values in all axis.

I try to use the accelerometer data (Gravity and UserAcceleration) but the results are really poor.
Do you have any idea about how can I get the rotation rate over Y-Axis?

Comment: I don't think it's available (yet), just gravity

Comment: Of course, pure speculation for the moment... But do you have any solution ?